# PhpStorm. CodeSniffer. Doesn't see the comment blocks

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpcodesniffer, inspections

PHP CodeSniffer doesn't see the doc blocks from PhpStorm inspection, but see them from the CLI. How to fix that?

Here is an example.

**From inspection**

[image]

**From CLI**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With local version of `phpcs` it's working. It could be found at `vendor/bin`.

I used the version, that is required in **Magento 2** `composer.json`. Now it is `1.5.3`.

Do not forget to run `composer update` in console to be sure, that `phpcs` is installed locally.